# Log a Call versus Task - Salesforce Flow Update

Tags: recordtriggeredflow, log-a-call

I am working on a flow to update various custom objects in our Org when a certain Call (Log a call) has specific dispositions. I am working in Sandbox so some of our features are not active (such as being able to use our phone integration to truly test), and it appears that debug doesn't work with Task.

My issue is I was able to get the update related record to work, but only if I tested with a Task and not a "Log a Call" option on the Contact record.

I am not sure what the difference is that caused it to work on "Task" and not "Log a Call" when they're the same "Activity".

I am still pretty new to writing flows and I may be missing something simple, but any support would be greatly appreciated.

Here are some images of the Flow:
[image]
[image]
[image]

What the Task versus the Call Log Looks Like:
[image: Call]
[image: Task]

Comment: As your flow only runs on record `is updated`, I suspect that for the `Task` use case, an actual DML Update occurs but for the `log  a call` - only a DML insert occurs. You might want to consider `created or updated` and `Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements`. The `Task` use case mighht involve other automation that causes the task to be updated (trigger, WFR, etc)

Comment: Oh that makes total sense! I completely missed that aspect. Thank you. I'll give it a try and edit with the result!

Comment: It worked! Such a simple miss that I made, thank you so much for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I surmise could be your issue

- The flow is defined to run only on `Update`
- Logging a Call via the UX  generates an insert, hence flow doesn't run
- Adding a Task via the UX generates an insert plus some subsequent automation on your org that causes an `Update` - hence the flow runs

Change your flow to `created or updated` and use the option `Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements` to avoid repeated firing every time the Task record is updated.